# cv2.imwrite("resized_"+image, re) throws syntax error

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I am using the following code to resize multiple images in one go but `cv2.imwrite("resized_"+image, re)` throws a syntax error. Looking forward to your answers

```
import cv2,glob

images=glob.glob("*.jpg")

for image in images:
    img=cv2.imread(image,1)
    re=cv2.resize(img,(int(img.shape[1]/4),int(img.shape[0]/4))
    cv2.imwrite("resized_"+image, re)
```

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

image is a filepath, it can cotain characters like '/', '\' - these are not valid in a filename in some filesystems.

So, just replace that part.

You had one closing bracket missing. Hence the syntax error.

```
import cv2,glob

images=glob.glob("*.jpg")

for image in images:
    img=cv2.imread(image,1)
    re=cv2.resize(img,(int(img.shape[1]/4),int(img.shape[0]/4)))
    print(re.shape)
    o = cv2.imwrite(image.split('.')[0] + '_replaced' + '.jpg', re)  
    print(o)
```

Comment: Thank You for your response but it still shows the syntax error. I was trying to replicate the code in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q93O_ilLZ50

Comment: though it worked but there are no resized files in the given folder.

Comment: check in the original folder where the images are loading from, I changed the path,

Comment: kindly, add the output from your next run.